# Is fckeditor free for use in freelance projects?

Tags: licensing, fckeditor

This is more of a licencing issue than a code question. I really like the [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) editor and would like to use it in my freelance projects which I do for clients. However upon reading the [license](http://ckeditor.com/license) page it has me in a bit of a confusion. DO I have to buy licences if I intend to use this in cms websites that I build myself and hand over to clients?

If so then what are my alternate options which don't cost anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its should be ok, if you don't change anything of its source, IMHO.

> Integrating CKEditor in **commercial**
>   software, taking care of satisfying
>   the Open Source licenses terms, while
>   not able or interested on supporting
>   CKEditor and its development.

Comment: Thats what got me confused - what does 'satisfying Open Source Licences Terms' mean.. whats the fine print?

Comment: According to LGPL, if you don't change anything of its source, and linking as library, would be ok for commercial projects too.

Comment: Oh so linking as library means the code is being used as it with no modifications whatsoever.. that doesn't include changing configuration files though does it? Sorry if I sound too jumpy here - had some bad experience with an image I used on a website a long time back, which explains why I'm being a bit extra cautious now.

Comment: Yeah, changing the configution files / changing the parameters should be ok, IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

I am not a lawyer, but the dual licensing model would appear to not prevent you from using the open source licensed CKEditor in your cms / client projects, as long as the terms of the chosen license are met.

What you cannot do is sell, give away or otherwise distribute the editor to third parties without providing them with access to the source code and the license attached to the product.

Comment: So basically as long as I include the whole download-able source code of the editor in my projects which I hand over to my clients - there should be no problem at all right? SO what are the other licenses there for actually?